# Magento2 : Delete Items From Core Config Data Table Using Standard Way

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

How can i delete core config data from magento2's database with standard way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be very useful.

```
public function __construct(
        Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\CollectionFactory $configCollectionFactory,
        Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data $configResource
    ) {
        $this->configCollectionFactory = $configCollectionFactory;
        $this->configResource    = $configResource;
    }
```

Use below code for deletion.

```
$configCollection = $this->configCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => "%" . $sectionId . "%"]);
        foreach ($configCollection as $configItem) {
            $this->configResource->delete($configItem);
        }
```